# Monogame project and ClickOnce

Tags: c#, clickonce, publish, monogame

I've made a stupid project to try monogame and now I want publish it to try to install it.
When I publish it and I install it, it says

> Cannot continue. The application is improperly formatted. Contact the application vendor for assistance.

It says so also if I uncheck "Signing > Sign the ClickOnce manifest".

I've tried also to unckeck "Security > Enable ClickOnce security settinigs"
In this case, it says:

> Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point to the [MSDN guide for deploying an XNA application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464156.aspx) which, even though you are using Monogame, shouldn't be all that different.

The highlights from the guide are in one of the possible problems regarding game content:

> **Special Considerations for Game Data Files**
>
> Your game may require the use of a data file to read and store
>   information. For example, the starter kit provided with XNA Game
>   Studio uses an XML file to read and store game settings. Other games
>   may use a text file or other format.
>
> The default behavior of the ClickOnce publishing wizard assigns any
>   XML, text, or other data files in a project to "Data File" as its
>   Publish Status. However, this status is for files containing data used
>   by the installer package, not for files accessible to your game when
>   it executes. Files assigned to this type will be placed in the path
>   denoted in the .NET Framework's ApplicationDeployment.DataDirectory
>   property.
>
> This is likely to be inconvenient, as the file will be inaccessible to
>   your game through conventional storage APIs. The recommended actions
>   to correct this are as follows:
>
> - Ensure the Build Action property of the data file is set to "Content." This specifies that the data file is to be included in the
>     install package.
> - Reassign the Publish Status to "Include."
>
> The Build Type setting may be changed through the file's property
>   window.
>
> The Publish Status is changed through the Application Files dialog box
>   of the  Publish properties section of Project Designer.

The last thing I can advise, given the simplicity of ClickOnce, is to try it out from the project publish options rather than the guided UI, as explained in [this guide](https://www.discussiongenerator.com/2012/08/26/build-xna-game-installer-clickonce/), also for XNA.

The process is the same, just go to the project properties and start the process from the Publish tab. Nothing out of the ordinary, but it allows you to set some special pre-requisites which the guided UI may be omiting:

> Click Prerequisites:
>
> - Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
> - Microsoft XNA Framework Redistributable 4.0
> - Windows Installer 3.1

Comment: I've not Windows Installer 3.1 in prerequisites